# Is there a book that lists major Jewish events that occurred on each day (Judaic calendar)?

Tags: history, jewish-books, calendar

A few months ago, I attended a shul on Shabbat that had a list of "notable" historic events that occurred on each Judaic date that was to occur in the following week. (E.g., if the week following was 7 - 14 Adar, it would list under 7 Adar - Moshe Rabbeinu's birth and death date and any other events; same for each date that week.) These events were printed on the back of the shul's weekly newsletter.

I can't imagine that the compiler scoured the web to find everything listed (each date had about 5 - 7 historic events.) Is there some book or online listing showing some historic events? I don't expect this to be a "full" list, of course, and I assume that any other would "randomly" choose what he wanted to include. I'm just looking for, say, a few sources, if they exist.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jewish-date-series

Comment: Time for a yearlong date series, instead of just part of a month?  Mi Yodeya - Tishrei 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a book DanF but quite useful. Click on the month in blue under This Day in Jewish History:  https://www.ou.org/blog/j101-topics/bh-yom-yom/

Comment: Perfect! This may be where the shul gets its info. It is an OU affiliated shul.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly as you described but: [https://www.amazon.com/Dor-LDor-Timeline-Year-Year/dp/1583302875](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1583302875)
If you want I can add an example picture from the book. 
Also, you can go to a month on the Yiddish Wikipedia site (e.g. [https://yi.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/חשוון](https://yi.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%95%D7%9F)) and click on a date; if you don’t understand Yiddish google translate can understand basics. 
And the same thing is on the Hebrew wiki. And the English to an extant (usually traditional and biblical events).

Comment: I'm not sure that the book is quite what I had in mind, but the concept is interesting. If it's on Google Books, let me know; otherwise you can include a pic.